# How to write a 24 bit message after reading from a 4-byte integer on a big endian machine (C)?

Tags: c, endianness, 24-bit

I am constructing a message to send a 24-bit number over the network.
For little endian machines, the code is (ptr is the pointer to the message buffer):

```
*ptr++ = (num >> 16) & 0xFF;
*ptr++ = (num >> 8)  & 0xFF;
*ptr++ = (num)       & 0xFF;
```

(So if num0, num1, num2 and num3 are the individual bytes making up num, the message would be encoded as `num2|num1|num0`.)

What should be the code for encoding `num2|num1|num0` on a big endian machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is portable regardless of endianess. The shift operators `>>` `<<` work with the values, not with the representation.

Answer (score 3):

The question here is, in what byte order shall the *message* be sent/constructed ? Because whether you are on a little or big endian machine doesn't matter with respect to `num`, as you're already dividing `num` into individual bytes in an endian-agnostic way.

The code you've posted stores 24 bits of `num` in big endian (aka network byte order). So if that's what you want you're already done. If you want to store it in big little instead, just reverse the order:

```
*ptr++ = (num)       & 0xFF;
*ptr++ = (num >> 8)  & 0xFF;
*ptr++ = (num >> 16) & 0xFF;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the receiving machine, regardless of endian-ness, if you receive them in same order as they are stored in ptr, assemble them like this:

```
num = (ptr[0] << 16) + (ptr[1] << 8) + (ptr[2]);
```

Comment: Thanks all for your responses. Will it be correct to summarize the responses as follows:

Comment: @Bikash, you hit enter too early?  :-)

Comment: 1. My protocol requires the byte order of the message to be big endian

Comment: 2. On the sender machine, I have uint32_t num, and I denote the 4 bytes of num as num0 ... num3, with num0 being the LSB and num3 the MSB. Under this scenario, the code posted sends the message in the desired format irrespective of the endianness of the sender machine.

Comment: 3. On the receiving machine, I read in num2 first, followed by num1 and then num0. So, in order to reconstruct the 24-bit version of num, I should use the following irrespective of the endianness of the receiving machine:

Comment: num24 = (num2 << 16) + (num1 << 8) + num0.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int a, b;
    a = 0x0f000000;        // Contain 32 bit value
    printf("before = %d\n", a);
    b = a & (~0xff000000); // convert the last 8 bits to zero so we got only 24 bit value in b
    printf("After = %d\n", b);
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

There is a number containing a 32-bit value but number b contains only 24 bits, starting from least significant digit. And that doesn't depend on endianness because bitwise operators don't work with memory representation.

So you can use

```
num = num & (~0xff000000);
```

to get the last 24-bit value.

Comment: It's also work so that time no need to Not operator (~ ) . That more optimal solution.